# VBA delete all worksheets in all workbooks that dont equal "summary details"

Tags: vba, excel

I cant seem to get the code to loop to the next workbook open. After that I would like to consolidate all the single worksheets in each workbook into a single workbook and rename each tab based on it's workbook name.

I am not too far but sentence one is my first task

```
  Sub cullworkbooksandCONSOLIDATE()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim wb As Workbook
        Dim wsNAME As String

            For Each wb In Application.Workbooks

            With wb
                For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

                    With ws
                        wsNAME = ws.Name
                        If wsNAME <> "summary details" Then
                            ws.Delete
                        End If

                    End With

                Next
            End With
            Next


    End Sub
```

thank you kindly

Comment: Are the names all aligned?  I would use the `wsNAME = LCase(ws.Name)` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or more directly, just copy the sheet if it exists, rather than deleting all the non matches (which will also cause an error if the code deletes all sheets)

```
Sub cullworkbooksandCONSOLIDATE()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim wsNAME As String


Set wb1 = Workbooks.Add(1)
wsNAME = "summary details"


For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    With wb
        If .Name <> wb1.Name Then 'if it's not the export workbook
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ws = wb.Sheets(wsNAME)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not ws Is Nothing Then ws.Copy Before:=wb1.Sheets(1)
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: would you mind walking me through your code and thought. My VBA is still at a low level and i dont understand objects yet. Also any resouce material would be amazing. I want to be a VBA expert.

Comment: The code creates a new workbook, then loops through all open workboos in the active instance. it checks that the workbook isnt the new created workbook, then looks to find a sheet in each open workbook with the name wsName ("summary details"). If it finds a sheet, then the variable ws exists (is not nothing), and that sheet is copied to the master workbook. If it doesnt find a matching sheet nothing happends for that workbook.

Comment: It is an almost perfect equivalent of mine, less structured (shouldn't matter in this size) but faster. It "selects" the ws and if there is none, it uses error handling. Only downside: it doesn't check for upper cases.

Comment: Checking for case wasn't specified  by the OP

Comment: is there a way to extend the code so that either on error the sheet is deleted and after it is copied the sheet is deleted. Or simpler a way to close each work book after the sheet is detected and copied? thank you for your walk through - error handling seems real nifty

Answer (score 0):

This is so not going into my resumé.

```
Sub cullworkbooksandCONSOLIDATE()
      Dim ws As Worksheet
      Dim wb As Workbook
      Dim wsNAME As String
      Dim wbex As Workbook
'You'll need to define wbex, this is where your worksheets will be inserted
For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
    With wb
        If .Name <> wbex.Name Then 'if it's not the export workbook
                For Each ws In wb.Worksheets 'not necessarily active workbook
                    With ws
                        wsNAME = LCase(.Name)
                        If wsNAME <> "summary details" Then
                            .Delete 'why do you need to delete it?
                        Else
                            .Name = wb.Name
                            .Copy Before:=wbex.Sheets(1)
                        End If
                    End With
                Next
            .Close SaveChanges:=False 'you really don't want to corrupt your source data, do you?
        End If
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much! I will test the code in the morning. Everyday I export 14 reports where i only need 1 sheet from each (the rest are summaries of the same data). From there I need to consolidate them and insert them into a worksheet where i then use those 14 report tabs and summarize for my management things... think TPS reports from Office Space.

Comment: Thank me when you see it working. If it does work though make sure you mark my answer as correct.

Comment: I wouldn't keep 14 tabs open at the same time. I would use the Open method with strings. You could place them like C:\ertdfgcvb.xlsx | Ertdfgcvb Co. | ertdfgcvb last:tab name. Your loop would then go through them, then copy their sheets/values and close them. Only two would be open at the same time.